# How to put a div at left or right in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I am new in **pure css**, it is nice and easy!

My HTML:

```
<header class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-1">
<div class="pure-u-4-5">

    <div class="left-in-header pure-u-3-8">This should be in left</div>

</div>

</header>
```

My CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('myfont.ttf');
}


html, button, input, select, textarea, *, * *,
.pure-g [class *= "pure-u"] {
    /* Set your content font stack here: */
    font-family: 'myfont', Times, "Times New Roman", serif !important;
}

html{
    direction:rtl;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


*, *:after, *:before{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header{
    color:white;
    background:#b90101;
    background: rgba(200,1,1,0.8);
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:2px 0!important;
}

header > div{
    margin:auto;
    display:block !important;
    background:red;

}

.left-in-header{
    background:green;

}
```

Now please see the green div with class `.left-in-header`, I want to put it at the left of its parent! (its size is `pure-u-3-8`).  *(My website language is Persian, and Persian is right to left, then my direction is rtl)*

**And How to put a div in center of it's parent by pure classes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give below css property to :

```
.pure-u-3-8{
 float:left;
text-align:left;
}
```

and remove `margin:auto` from div itslef and its parent if given

Comment: Thanks, but I know this is not standard way in pure-css!!  and I need that margin:auto to put the div to center

Comment: even if you do not remove margin:auto still it will work due to float:left property

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox might be a good idea, it respects text direction when defined, e.g. `<html dir="rtl" ...>`.

The alignment can be achieved by setting `display: flex` and `justify-content: flex-end` (or different, for example `space-between` or `space-around`, if you wish to align more items in a different way) to the parent. For more options see this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.